# Uniform integrability with respect to a family of measures

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, levy-processes, uniform-integrability

Let $(\mu_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ be a sequence of Levy measures such that:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\mu_n(E) = \mu(E), \quad (\forall\,\,  E \,\, \mu-\hbox{Continuity set}, 0 \notin \overline{E})$$
where $\mu$ is another Levy measure. All measures are defined on Borelians of $\mathbb R^m$. Suppose that:
$$\int_{\mathbb R^m} |x|^2 \mu_n (dx)\leq C \quad \forall n \in \mathbb N.$$
Given $A=[-a,a]^p = [-a,a] \times \cdots \times [-a,a]$, where $a >0$. I want to show that
\begin{equation}\label{I}\tag{I}
\int_{A^c}x \mu_n(dx) \longrightarrow \int_{A^c}x \mu(dx), \quad (n \to \infty) 
\end{equation}
Recall that by definition of Levy measures, we have $\mu_n (A^c)< \infty$ and $\mu(A^c)< \infty$.

I was trying to use a uniform integrability argument, but the definition of uniform integrability concerns a family of Random Variables. In this case, I have a family (sequence) of measures.

How to show (\ref{I})?

Comment: Did you mean to write $\to$ instead of $=$?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want. I just fixed this.